# R caret package question

Tags: r, caret

```
library(car)
library(caret)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(Prestige$income, p=.7, list=F)
prestige.train <- Prestige[trainIndex, ]
prestige.test <- Prestige[-trainIndex, ]
my.grid <- expand.grid(.decay = c(0.5, 0.1), .size = c(5, 6, 7))
prestige.fit <- train(income ~ prestige + education, data = prestige.train,
    method = "nnet", maxit = 1000, tuneGrid = my.grid, trace = F, linout = 1)
prestige.predict <- predict(prestige.fit, newdata = prestige.test)
prestige.rmse <- sqrt(mean((prestige.predict - prestige.test$income)^2))
```

The above was discussed here 
[How to train and validate a neural network model in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21717/how-to-train-and-validate-a-neural-network-model-in-r)

1. Does caret package run many times for combinations of decay and size? If so, what is the default # of iterations?
2. What is the final choice of decay and size? When I do `summary(prestige.fit)`, the decay is 0.5 and size is 5. Is that the final combination that caret chose as best option?

Answer (score 2):

1) First off, yes the neural net models are run for every unique combination of .decay and .size that you've supplied in `my.grid` because, well, you created it. If you just specified `my.grid = data.frame('.decay'=0.5, '.size'=5)`, then you would only have one model.

As far as iterations are concerned, you specified the backend modeling application to be the `nnet` function from the `nnet` package, so these models are estimated using back-propagation which is an iterative gradient descent process that stops once it converges (or diverges). It could be one iteration if you specify parameters that give a local maximum in the entropy space for your algorithm initialization. Alternately, it could iterate `1000` times and and fail, since you specified `maxit=1000`. This refers to the model *fitting* process.

Also built into this innocuous train function is a validation approach where you pick the best set of params from `my.grid` according to some objective measure and resampling process. The objective measure is specified by hand or by the value of your outcome `metric = ifelse(is.factor(y), "Accuracy", "RMSE")`. So depending on `income` (probably continuous), you pick grid options that minimized root mean square error (minimal bias / variance trade off, a good starting place). The method of cross validation is default bootstrap with a staggering default number of resamples being *10*. See `?trainControl`. Considering this is parallelized, I'm shocked. In my thesis, we weren't quite happy with `10,000` resamples.

2) Your specific model gives the combo in `my.grid` for which you have minimal RMSE in the pooled 10 bootstrap resamples cross validated model outcome.

Comment: Thank you. That helped understanding what caret was trying to do. I have a classification problem that i am working on. Is there a way i can summarize AUC ( area underthe curve ) or missclassification rate for all the my.grid options that i supply ? Thank you..

Comment: Have you looked at `?train`?

Comment: I just did i am not sure how i can summarize missclassification rate for all the different combinations.

Comment: Income is continuous. What are you classifying?

Comment: The prestige dataset above was an example i used for discussion. The model i have has a binary outcome and i wonder how i can summarize misclassification rate for each combination of decay and size.

Comment: You'd summarize misclassification rate for each combination of decay and size the same way you'd summarize misclassification rate overall. Probably not worth a different CV question altogether since it's been asked a billion times. I'd start with reviewing [Cohen's Kappa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen's_kappa) which is already a built-in option for `train`.

Comment: The default is bootstrapping with 30 iterations. I picked this to be computationally light as the package runs `train` several times during R CMD check. 30 it too much but, IMO, not by much unless your sample size is small.